# Finding the DE of family of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

FInd the DE of the family of circles in XY plane passing through the points $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $(\pm1,1)$ by $(\pm1,0)$ for the moment.

By symmetry it is sufficient to consider a point $P=(x,y)$ in the (interior of) the first quadrant. The circle through $(\pm1,0)$ and $(x,y)$ has its center at $M=(0,c)$ with
$$c={x^2+y^2-1\over 2y}\ .$$
The vector $MP$ has slope ${y-c\over x}$; therefore the tangent to the circle through $P$ with center $M$ has slope
$$-{x\over y-c}={2xy\over x^2-y^2-1}$$
at $P$. It follows that the DE of "my" family of circles is given by
$$y'={2xy\over x^2-y^2-1}\ .$$
In order to obtain the DE for "your" family of circles we have to move this "slope field" one unit up, so that we end with
$$y'={2x(y-1)\over x^2-(y-1)^2-1}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

I have taken circles passing through $ x= \pm 1, y=1$ as

$$ x^2 (y-1)^2 - 2 h (y-1) = 1 \tag{1} $$

where $h$ can influence a variable radius size so as to eliminate it by differentiation.

Differentiate and simplify

$$  h= \frac{x + y y^{\prime} -y^{\prime}}{y^{\prime}}  \tag{2} $$

Plug in (2) to eliminate $h$ into (1) and simplify

$$  y^{\prime} ( \frac{x^2+y^2}{2} -y ) = (y-1) (x + y \,y^{\prime} -y^{\prime}) \tag {3} $$

Further simplification gives

$$  y^{\prime} = \frac{2x (y-1) }{(x^2-y^2 + 2 y -2 ) } \tag{4}$$

Actually it is better to (give in problem and ) use a symbol to check errors at each stage.

$$  y^{\prime} = \frac{2x (y-a) }{(x^2-y^2 + 2 a y -2 a^2) }$$