# Forming Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, differential

Find the DE of the family of circles in $xy$ plane passing through the points $(−1,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

The question was asked earlier also [Finding the DE of family of curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/432769/301067) but the answer was a tad weird. Any further simplification?

Comment: What is weird here ?

Comment: Not weird per se. But is that the only way to solve it?

Comment: Probably not, but you'll get the same answer, as it is the right one.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you. :)